# Protractor and asynchronous property of JS

Tags: asynchronous, protractor, automated-tests

I wanted to ask about this in general, but I had concerns switching my frontend automation suite from a Java framework to a JavaScript one. Mainly around an individual test running asynchronously.

Could cases potentially happen where tests take steps out of order or do a false positive of passing a test before the last expect argument is resolved?

If they can, in general, how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to handle asynchronous nature of JS with Protractor:
1) Use async/await 
or
2) User control flow (this basically means that if you are not using async/await you are using the Control Flow. It can not be combined as far as I know)
If you are not familiar with the async/await you can simply write your tests in synchronous manner e.g:

```
browser.get("https://myurl.com")
element(by.id("login").sendKeys("admin")
element(by.id("password").sendKeys("secretpassword")
element(by.buttonText("Login!").click()
expect(element(by.cssContainingText("header", "Welcome Admin")).toBePresent()
```

Protractor will execute this code in synchronous manner and the biggest plus is that it will actually wait for your Angular application to be ready (nevertheless you will have to use smart waits (Protractor expect condition) from time to time)
Before executing your tests protractor will build a queue of your steps and will execute it one by one since most of this steps are build upon promises. All none-protractor/webdriver method will be added to the call stack in common asynchronous manner. E.g. if you will add console.log("foo") at the end of the previous code snippet it will print the console.log before executing the steps.
This is pretty poor explanation but hope it will help